# Not getting full data from api to Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, api, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

Hello CS community,

```
r = requests.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/")
x = r.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(x['results'])
```

I am using these lines to get the data from this api to my jupyter notebook for my big data class but somehow I am getting only 19 lines/rows. Could you please help me load the whole data? Or should it be somehow by 19 and then delete and other 19?

Thank you guys!

Comment: not possible... the api result is a json of 1118 objects

Comment: try https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=9999 it seems that limit defaults to 20. This limitation might be useful if the client who consume the API is computer with small memory (e.g.: microcontrollers, SBCs, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `api` is loading only `20` records at a time.

If you see carefully, it has a `next` key in it. You can do something like this:

```
In [467]: r = requests.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/")
In [471]: x = r.json()

In [476]: data = []
In [477]: data.append(x['results'])

# Loop until `next` is `None`
In [478]: while x.get('next'):
     ...:     r = requests.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/")
     ...:     x = r.json()
     ...:     data.append(x['results'])
     ...: 

In [473]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This should get you all the records.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the number of record that you want at once in url query string `limit`.

ex: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=9999

It seems that limit defaults to 20.

This limitation might be useful to both:

- the client (API consumer), for example, if the client is computer with small memory (e.g.: microcontrollers, SBCs, etc);
- and useful for the server (API server), for example, to reduce memory and bandwidth usage

Be advised that such habit (changing the limit to max number) might not always be good. Your client app might:

- get slower (since it needs to load all data at once from network; and possibly need to parse the json/xml),
- might need more memory,
- might consume more metered data connection,
- and might consume more battery (reasons above)